# SMTP Mail code working form local host but not fom server

Tags: asp.net, email, smtp

SMTP mail code working from ASP .net local server but not from server here is my code :

```
protected void btn_send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
    mail.To.Add("to gmail address");
    mail.From = new MailAddress("from gmail address", "Email head", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
    mail.Subject = "This mail is send from asp.net application";
    mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    mail.Body = "This is Email Body Text";
    mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("from gmail address", "your gmail account password");
    client.Port = 587;
    client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    try
    {
        client.Send(mail);
        Page.RegisterStartupScript("UserMsg", "<script>alert('Successfully Send...');if(alert){ window.location='SendMail.aspx';}</script>");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Exception ex2 = ex;
        string errorMessage = string.Empty;
        while (ex2 != null)
        {
            errorMessage += ex2.ToString();
            ex2 = ex2.InnerException;
        }
        Page.RegisterStartupScript("UserMsg", "<script>alert('Sending Failed...');if(alert){ window.location='SendMail.aspx';}</script>");
    }
```

This is not working as per expected. I'm trying to send an email from feedback form.

Comment: _"not working as expected"_ isn't really helpful. What _is_ it doing? What error message do you get?

Comment: Hi... There is no error but message sending field..